# 07 Honda Odyssey timing belt change interval for "normal" driving conditions?

Tags: honda, scheduled-maintenance, timing-belt

The owners manual for my 2007 Honda Odyssey seems to indicate that the timing belt should be changed at 60,000 miles for extreme driving conditions.  It's not clear what the schedule is for normal conditions.  I've heard 90,000, is that accurate?

Answer (score 1):

The manual should have a section for "normal" as well as "severe".  Given the expense of repairs on an interference engine (which I *believe* all Hondas are), I'd be inclined to replace it on the "severe" schedule unless I drove 20,000+ miles a year all highway.  Severe service *may* include cars that are not driven lots of miles in a year as some items (typically belts, hoses, tires) are time limited in addition to wear limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the online Owner's Manual for your vehicle does not specify the mileage and rather defers to the Maintenance Minder feature of your vehicle. This is unfortunate, I can check the service manual later and see if it species whether the maintenance minder is hard coded or if it would produce variable recommendations like some other vehicles are starting to do based on programming around your driving characteristics.

To my knowledge, under normal driving conditons your maintenance minder should have you change the timing belt, get a major tune-up and have valves adjusted at 105K. It's a really big hit on maintenance... but after that you are fairly low maintenance until 210K!! (supposedly)

For our 1999 and 2005 Odyssey LX models this was the dealership recommendation for our driving type.

rich

Comment: I'd definitely be interested in seeing what the service manual says.  I've heard 90k from a local shop, but that's probably because I'm at 83k now :)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Brian, that it isn't all about "miles" per se. Things like timing belts are going to degrade more with time than miles (but with both) so divide the 90K by average driving (12K per year). If you are close to that time period, go ahead and change the belt out. Interference engines are nothing to fool with.

Answer (score 0):

I bought my '07 Odyssey Touring back in 2013 having 75k on it. Now, it's got about 101k. It was prolly due then based on the 60k rule...or 90. I'll wait till it gets to 120k then I'll have the timing belt changed. Based on my past Hondas that I took to their limits, they broke/worn out pretty much between 140-170K miles. Thats why I think 120k will atill be safe. One example: I had a 1991 CRX DX (died on the I-5 fwy) with timing belt's teeth mostly worn out, literally. The amazing part was, there was no issue with valves hitting the cylinders, for a '91 model. I thought the valve clearance improvement only happened in the '95s-up on Hondas.